# Injecting a Polymer web-component into head with JavaScript's appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm trying to use JS to load a web-component in a page that let's me plugin my code, but not modify the `<head>`'s contents.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.23/webcomponents-lite.min.js";

  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.rel = "import";
  link.href = "https://my-cdn.com/build/my-widget.html";

  [script, link].forEach(function(element) {
    document.head.appendChild(element);
  });
</script>
```

However, this throws the following errors while adding the `script` tag itself:

> webcomponents-lite.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: window.wrap is not a function(…)`

A plain HTML page with the equivalent `script` and `link` tags inside `head` work just fine! Any idea how I can accomplish this? The page does pre-load jQuery, so I'm able to use jQuery if needed - but this seemed fairly trivial to me, so have attempted a pure-JS solution.

Comment: @Supersharp thanks - the original code had it anyway but have updated the qn with the correct code. My error occurs because the page seems to contain another div with ID `wrap` already - and this is something I can't control since I'm only injecting code :-(

Answer (score 1):

Indeed if the error is due to a conflict with another global `wrap`, it's annoying :-(

Maybe you could try one of these solutions:

- Undefine the `wrap` variable just before appending the `<script>`: `var wrap = undefined`, but maybe it's not a good idea to redefine it if it's expected elsewhere ;
- Use another equivalent polyfill: https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element ;
- Rename the `window.wrap` function in the current polyfill. It's easier that one could imagine (11 ocurrences, that you can rename to `wrap2`).

Comment: Thanks! I've modified `webcomponentjs` by setting this `if` branch to always run: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/9387b123767397584698d9a403aefcc640572179/src/CustomElements/boot.js#L50 like so: `if (true || !window.wrap) {` (in case I want to un-fix it later).

Now from the Polymer's `link` tag, I see this: > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)
Line: `if (element && rule.propertyInfo.properties && matchesSelector.call(element, rule.transformedSelector || rule.parsedSelector)) {` where `var matchesSelector = Polymer.DomApi.matchesSelector;`

Comment: `Element.match` and `Element.prototype.matches` seem to be at conflict with each other - I think `iframe` is my only way out. God damn :-'(

Comment: did you try one the 3 above solutions? you're 2 comments are not related to them

Comment: no they are - my approach solves all errors inside the script-element being appending. The remaining errors and with the link-element being appended. The second error seems to be a conflict between Polymer and PrototypeJS (being used by the page that I don't have control over) in how they mutate the Element class

Comment: So they are not related to your question and to my answer

Comment: I'm not sure what you're missing - I just explained exactly why it's impossible to run Polymer in the webpage I'm dealing with in exactness. Which is extremely related to the question as well as to your answer :| anyway, thanks for your time! +1

Comment: ok then you should update your question of adding comments in my answer so that other user can answer to these new errors. Thank you anyway+1